Resampling every 2 months and calculate the band average of the resampling
I'm new to python and I'd like some advice on my question.
My aim is to group the images by tile, then, depending on the date and the band number, to do a temporal resampling by band (between individual bands) every two months.
In fact, I'm working on time series of satellite images, i.e. a total of 1836 images or dates.  The images are named as follows, for example ( T29PQN_20220507T103631_B01_20m_masked.tif, T29PRP_20220607T103631_B12_20m_masked.tif).
T29PQN: corresponds to the tile numbers, geographical footprints (in total there are T29PPP', 'T29PPQ', 'T29PQN', 'T29PQP', 'T29PQQ', 'T29PRP', 'T29PRQ').
20220507T103631 = This is the date.
B01 = Band number (there are 12 bands per date). Here's the code I'm writing:
# list initialization
list_T29PPP = []
list_T29PPQ = []
list_T29PQN = []
list_T29PQP = []
list_T29PQQ = []
list_T29PRP = []
list_T29PRQ = []
list_test = []
# list of tile names
liste_tile = ['T29PPP', 'T29PPQ', 'T29PQN', 'T29PQP', 'T29PQQ', 'T29PRP', 'T29PRQ'] 
for msk_list in im_msk:

    tile_name = msk_list.split('/')[7][0:6] # T29PPP
    date_month = msk_list.split('_')[8][4:6] # 05
    band_name = msk_list.split('_')[9][:] # B01
    msk_file = glob.glob(f"{path_dir}S2A_MSIL2A_*/*{tile_name}*{date_month}*{band_name}*_masked.tif")
    print(msk_file)

    if tile_name == liste_tile[0]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PPP.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[1]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PPQ.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[2]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PQN.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[3]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PQP.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[4]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PQQ.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[5]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PRP.append(msk_list)
    if tile_name == liste_tile[6]:
        if len(msk_file) > 0:
            list_T29PRQ.append(msk_list)
    elif len(msk_file) == 0:
        list_test.append(msk_list)

    else:
        print('No file found')


# Next step:

``
# 1. aggregate for each tile name temporal resampling with 2 months


# 2. Next steps coumpute mean  for resampled images

Thanks in advance!

What is your question? What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Thank you and I am sorry for my late feedback, the code runs without any issues in this step. I'm confused about how to proceed to the next steps.
My questions are: How can I aggregate temporal resampling for each tile with 2 months? How can I compute the mean for resampled images?
